# How to set default DateField value as current date?

Tags: django, django-models

I am working on a project where a user can enter the date and also can leave the field empty. I am using Abstract User for storing the date using DateField. However when user leaves the field empty, it does not store current date as value but remains empty.

## models.py

```
import datetime

class CustomUser(AbstractUser):
    date_of_joining = models.DateField(default=datetime.date.today,blank=True,null=True)
```

Answer (score 0):

Just use this:

```
date_of_joining = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
```

Comment: It throws : 'date_of_joining' cannot be specified for CustomUser model form as it is a non-editable field

Comment: First you tell me that if you are using custom user, did you configure it in setting.py file?

Comment: show me models.py file code where you are defining this model

Comment: That's what I have put in the question.

Comment: I want to see all the import statements? Are you importing only datetime

Comment: from django.db import models |
from django.conf import settings |
from django.contrib.auth.models import AbstractUser

Comment: if you are importing the `models` then it should allow you to create that field.

Answer (score 0):

Try  setting blank and null to `False`.

Comment: Use can leave the field empty during form submission. Can't set their value to False.